# Form action is not calling the required function from views.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and doing my first project in it. I had made a form in my `index.html` file and that form took an image, and sent it to a `predictImage` function in `views.py` file. The `predictImage` function applied YOLO model on the image and returned the image with labels to the same `index.html` page.

This was **working fine and I was getting the required results**. After the submit button was clicked, I was getting redirected to ***index.html/predictImage*** where the results were being shown. (I had conditions added in my index.html to show the results)

Then, I decided to add a **Users** Model and made a Login page for me, user was required to login before he could upload the image. For this, I added sessions as well.

Now, I created a **Photo** model, to store every photo that every user uploads. All of this was successfully made but now, when I tried to do the same thing again, i.e., upload the image and submit it, it didn't work and it instead ***redirected me to index.html***

I tried to debug this, and I found out that I was not even going to **views.predictImage** when I clicked the submit button. I don't seem to understand why this was happening, even though the only two new things that I added in my **index.html** were a hidden input file (to get the value of username from session) and a Logout Button to log out from the session.

Here is my **models.py** file (I added Photos Model later on)

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
import os
# Create your models here.


class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField('User Name', null=False, max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField('User Password', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

def filepath(request, filename):
    old_filename = filename
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S')
    filename = "%s%s" % (timeNow, old_filename)
    return os.path.join('uploads/', filename)

class Photo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=filepath) 
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(Users, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my **urls.py** file, no changes were made to this.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path 
from firstApp import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('index', views.index, name = 'index'),
    re_path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    re_path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    re_path('', views.login, name="Login"),
    # re_path('', views.login_submit, name='Home'),
    re_path('predictImage', views.predictImage, name='predictImage'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my **views.py** file

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.session.has_key('is_logged'):
        return redirect('index')
    if request.POST:
        if 'user_name' not in request.POST:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
        username_entry = request.POST['user_name']
        password = request.POST['password']
        count = Users.objects.filter(username=username_entry).count()
        if count > 0:
            user_password = Users.objects.values('password').filter(username=username_entry)[0]
            if password == user_password['password']:
                request.session['is_logged'] = True
                request.session['user_id'] = request.POST['user_name']
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid Password")
                return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Username")
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    


def index(request):
    if request.session.has_key('is_logged'):
        current_user_id= request.session['user_id']
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'ID':current_user_id})
    else:
        return redirect('login')


    # context = {'a':1}
    # return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def predictImage(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    print("HEREEEE: ", username) # was using to check if this function is being called or not
    # All the below lines are irrelevant to the bug
    # They are only saving the Image file and calling YOLO Model Function to get Resultant image
    # All of this was worknig before as well 
    fileObj = request.FILES['filePath']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filePathName = fs.save(fileObj.name, fileObj)
    filePathName = fs.url(filePathName)
    testimage = '.'+filePathName
    img_result, resultant_array, total_objects = detect_image(testimage)
    cv2.imwrite("media/results/" + fileObj.name, img=img_result)

    context = {'filePathName':"media/results/"+fileObj.name, 'predictedLabel': list(resultant_array.keys()), 'values': list(resultant_array.values()), 'total_objects': total_objects}
    #context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def logout(request):
    del request.session['is_logged']
    return redirect('login')
```

And this is my **index.html** file (only containing the portion where the form exists, I can share the rest of the file if needed but that isn't linked to this problem as far as I know)

```
  {% csrf_token %}


  <div id="content">

    <!-- Topbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light  m-5 mx-5 justify-content-center">

      <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
      <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>

      <!-- Topbar Search -->
      <div class=" mx-5 font-weight-bold">
        Uplaod Image
      </div>
      <input class=" " type="file" name="filePath">
      <input hidden class = "" name="username" value="{{ ID }}">
      <input type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success" value="Submit">
      <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
    </form>

      <a class="btn-lg btn-danger" href={% url 'logout' %}>  Logout</a>


    </nav>
    <!-- End of Topbar -->
```